# Terminating threads in Java with several requests?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have a method in a CLIENT Java application (ie Android app)

```
ExecutorService pool = ExecutorsService.newFixedThreadPool(1); //1 thread in pool

public void makeHTTPRequestVeryVeryCostly() { 
  /* IN A BACKGROUND THREAD */
   CompleteableFuture<String> s = CompleteableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> makeCostlyReq, pool));  
   s.get();
   updateTheUserUIInTheMainUIThread(s); //Update with s
}

button.onClicklistener((b) -> makeHTTPRequestVeryVeryCostly()); // some button in the UI that will make the http request
```

In anger, the user taps the button 100 times, then 100 requests have been submitted into the ThreadPool. 2 bad things occur:

(1) Costly request computed 100 times

(2) The UI is refreshed 100 times after each return.

These are all very big issues. In Java, what's the way of solving this? It would be best to terminate all preceeding requests in the thread pool after one sucessful request, how can this be done?

Comment: Good question, but the title could use some tweaking (not clear).

Comment: Simple solution: disable the button after the first click, so no additional requests can be added. Or otherwise a volatile/atomic flag which you set and/or check when starting a request, and unset upon completion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want send each http request, but no concurrency。 `Lock` may help you here. Below pseudo-code:

```
ExecutorService pool = ExecutorsService.newFixedThreadPool(1); //1 thread in pool
Lock httpRequestLock = new ReentrantLock();

public void makeHTTPRequestVeryVeryCostly() {
   boolean locked = httpRequestLock.tryLock(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   if(!locked){
     //can't get the request lock util timeout(10s)
     return;
   }

   try{
      /* IN A BACKGROUND THREAD */
       CompleteableFuture<String> s = CompleteableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> makeCostlyReq, pool));  
       s.get();
       updateTheUserUIInTheMainUIThread(s); //Update with s
   }finally{
       httpRequestLock.unlock();
   }
}

button.onClicklistener((b) -> makeHTTPRequestVeryVeryCostly()); // some button in the UI that will make the http request
```

We use a `Lock` to ensure only one request at same time, and set a timeout to follow-up request when get lock to send a request.

**In addition**, if you just want a user just send request in a low frequency，like 1 time/10s。You can declare a variable to keep last time the request sent, and every time check the duration between the last execute time and current time.